# DynamoDB update multiple items by attribute value

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Considering the following simplified DynamoDB table:

- UserId (PK)
- PhoneNumber
- AuthAttempts

Where the same **PhoneNumber** can be shared across items. Eg:

UserId: 1
PhoneNumber: 1111
AuthAttempts: 1

UserId: 2
PhoneNumber: 1111
AuthAttempts: 1

UserId: 3
PhoneNumber: 2222
AuthAttempts: 0

Would it be possible to update the **AuthAttempts** attribute for all items matching the same **PhoneNumber**?

Comment: Judging by the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862368/how-to-update-all-records-in-dynamodb and the lack of useful internet search results on the topic, I suspect that DynamoDB has no way of doing this efficiently. You probably *will* have to fetch the keys of matching items, and then update all of them individually. You can at least bundle some of the updates in a batch request, but that's still individual item update commands, just bundled in one big API request.